# Need help understanding pixel position on different screen

Tags: windows, image, math, vnc

I am trying to understand how do VNC or remote control software keep track of click across screen sizes? For example I am showing an image or screen to a small 720p screen from a 1080p screen. If I click px(x,y) on 720p display, how can I calculate and find out the exact point in 1080p display?

I was thinking of calculating it with aspect ratio like image scaling. But I think that is not required and the screen/window size can be any.
So I need math or explanation on how to accomplish exact pixel finding. Any help will be appreciated.

test code to find nthPixel:

```
#img = old/parent screen size
#sc = new/schild screen

imgW = 100 
imgH = 100

scW = 90 #100 , 50, 1000
scH = 100

wDiff = imgW - scW
hDiff = imgH - scH

n = 2 # 50, 99

nthPixelOnW = wDiff * (imgW / 2) #??? how to find nth pixel?

nthPixelOnH = hDiff * (imgH / 2) #??? how to find nth pixel?

print("Hello, w, h = ", nthPixelOnW , nthPixelOnH)
```

Comment: If you use scrollbars: you just add the x and y offsets to the click coordinate. If you've scaled the screen, you scale the click coordinate accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Can we find scrollbar offsets without using scrollbars and by getting the difference of new and old images or screen sizes?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sir, by scale do you mean to multiply it or add the difference or add the average or something else?

Comment: I got it. Just multiplying with respective factors (w/w, h/h) with nth value will give result.